# validate domain trust command, netdom trust /verify doesn't work

Tags: active-directory, command-line-interface, trust-relationship

I have an external trust with my Active Directory domain. I want to validate the trust from a command so that I can do it remotely and don't have to open Remote Desktop and navigate to the AD domains and trusts console. I have read that *netdom trust TrustingDomainName /d:TrustedDomainName /verify* should work, but it does not. Whether locally or via psexec, I get *The command failed to complete successfully.* with an error code of 5.

Anyone know a command that does work?

Comment: Netdom is the command tool to use.  I don't think Powershell's test-computersecurechannel will do the job.  For the netdom trust /verify command, try using admin credentials (Domain/Enterprise Admin) for both domains using the switches /PasswordO: /UserO: and /PasswordD: /UserD:

Answer (score 1):

If access is denied for Netdom commands across a trust, you likely need to enable the **Network access: Allow anonymous SID/Name translation** group policy object on each domain controller.

The GPO is located in **Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options**

Source - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-allow-anonymous-sidname-translation

Answer (score 0):

Error code 5 for Access is denied, you didn't have a appropriate rights to verify the Domain trust, should have a Domain admin/enterprise admin right or use run as with account which has a required access